# How to install Shotwell Unstable from Flathub?

Tags: shotwell

https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Shotwell/BuildingAndInstalling

I'm sure there's documentation somewhere, but I have no idea how to install the unstable version. Is there a step-by-step guide?

Comment: Why would you want to install an unstable version of Shotwell? Doesn't the stable version work for you?

Comment: @heynnema I had wanted the face detection feature which is still a WIP but it still has enough functionality for me.

Answer (score 0):

Copy the link provided (in this case, click the "Install Unstable" button - the link should be https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/shotwell/raw/master/flatpak/org.gnome.Shotwell.unstable.flatpakref). Then, in a terminal, run `flatpak install [LINK]` (where LINK is https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/shotwell/raw/master/flatpak/org.gnome.Shotwell.unstable.flatpakref).